# Observable class property doesn't trigger subscription

Tags: c#, .net-core, rx.net

Simple observable variable works as expected an triggers callback immediately on the same thread. 
Why a class variable of any observable type (Subject, ISubject, Observable, IObservable) doesn't trigger callback?

**Example with simple variable** - [Works]

```
var x1 = new Subject<string>();
var x2 = x1.DistinctUntilChanged();

x2.Subscribe(o =>
{
  // Triggered as expected
});

x1.OnNext("Hello");
```

**Example with a class** - [Does NOT work]

```
public class InstrumentModel
{
  public Subject<string> Demo => new Subject<string>();
}

var class1 = new InstrumentModel();

class1.Demo
  //.DistinctUntilChanged()
  //.SubscribeOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
  //.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
  .Subscribe(o =>
{
  // Never triggered 
});

class1.Demo.OnNext("Hello");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you made `Demo` to return new instance of `Subject<string>` every time it is used.

`Demo` instance that you subscribed too, is not the same instance you called `OnNext()` on.

```
class1.Demo.Subscribe(...); // makes new instance `Subject<string>`

class1.Demo.OnNext("Hello"); // makes another new instance of `Subject<string>`
```

Keep it the same instance and it will work. For example:

```cs
public class InstrumentModel
{
  public Subject<string> Demo = new Subject<string>();
}
```

or:

```
public class InstrumentModel
{
    public InstrumentModel()
    {
        this.Demo = new Subject<string>();
    }
    public Subject<string> Demo { get; }
}
```